# pandas join on multi index with criteria on one level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1 indexed with 3 levels and df2 indexed with the same 3 levels.
Let's assume `date,name,criteria` are the 3 columns by which those 2 dataframes are indexed.

I would like to "join" `df2` to `df1` such that for each level of index `a_date,a_name,a_criteria` in `df1`, the values that are joined from `df2` match `a_date,a_name,specific_criteria` where `specific_criteria` is a constant value.

I end up doing something like the below and was wondering if there was a more elegant way ?

```py
new_df1= pd.DataFrame()
for group_name, group_df in df1.groupby(level=[0, 1]):
    index_level = group_name + ("0M","field_v1",)
    group_df["bla2"] = df2.loc[index_level, "bla2"]
    new_df1 = pd.concat([new_df1, group_df])
```

Sample data :

`df1:`

```
date    asset   tenor   bla value
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 100 0.155346154
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 102.5   0.150401253
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 105 0.142983901
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 107.5   0.137154123
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 110 0.133267604
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  112.5   0.130425064
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  115 0.126161253
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  117.5   0.12344318
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  120 0.121631132
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  80  0.210254154
```

`df2:`

```
tenor   field   bla2    date
0M  field_v1    351.91  1/3/2005
0M  field_v2    351.91  1/3/2005
0M  field_v3    347.7   1/3/2005
```

I would like to obtain the following `result_df1` (`bla2` value (351.91) for `(1/3/2005,AEX,0M,field_v1")` in `df2` for all `(1/3/2005,AEX)` lines in `df1` :

```
date    asset   tenor   bla value   bla2
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 100 0.155346154 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 102.5   0.150401253 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 105 0.142983901 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 107.5   0.137154123 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 12M 110 0.133267604 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  112.5   0.130425064 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  115 0.126161253 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  117.5   0.12344318  351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  120 0.121631132 351.91
1/3/2005    AEX 6M  80  0.210254154 351.91
```

Comment: Is possible some sample data?

Comment: Just added some short sample data and updated the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working filter by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and then [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df22 = df2.xs(('0M','field_v1'), level=[2,3])
new_df1 = df1.join(df22)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to someone, you can in fact do

```py
df1["tenor2"] = "0M"
df1["field"] = "field_v1"
df1.set_index(["date","tenor2","field"]
df2.set_index(["date","tenor","field"]
df1.join(df2)
```

EDIT : better solution by @jezrael